# How to change color of marker line (ladder) for annotation in google line chart?

Tags: annotations, google-visualization, marker

In google line chart, "There are two styles of annotations: letter (default), which draws the annotation text near the specified point, and **line**, which draws the annotation text on a line that bisects the chart area." I tried to remove the line/annotation marker, but found no way to do the same. Here is the overview of what I did

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
```

...
and 
...
        `chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementByI`d('test'));
...
and in options, i added

**annotations: {style: 'default', textStyle:{fontSize:25,color:'red',bold:true}}**

and finally

```
chart.draw(data, options);
```

the annotations option works only for text and I found no way /option for the marker (vertical line/ladder). I want to remove the marker for annotation. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using annotation in line chart. In the annotation style customization only available. Here cannot be change color and font size.

```
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    var options = {
              annotation: {
                     1: {
                            style: 'default'
                         }
                      }
                  };
```